# Vue-js sliding pagination

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination

**Problem statement :**

I need to make a pagination, Issue which I am facing is that `next` button on first page is not working. If I go to second page, the next button works perfectly.

Can someone please explain what wrong I am doing and if you can suggest some articles on the subject of `pagination`.

This is my HTML **:**

```
<sliding-pagination
:current="currentPage"
:total="totalPages"
@page-change="pageChangeHandler"
></sliding-pagination>
```

This is my Vue **:**

```
import SlidingPagination from 'vue-sliding-pagination'

// in component or vue instance
components: {
  SlidingPagination
},
data() {
  return {
    currentPage: 1,
    totalPages: 10
  }
},
methods: {
  pageChangeHandler(selectedPage) {
    this.currentPage = selectedPage
  }
}
```

Comment: The provided code is not enough to pin point the problem. Please provide more code, preferably a working example, e.g. on codesandbox